# PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'documentai.processors.processOnline' denied on resource '//documentai.googleapis.com/project...'(or it may not exist)."

Tags: google-iam, google-cloud-iam, cloud-document-ai

ISSUE: i want to use the same documents ai custom-trained processor from several different projects. the approach i have in mind is to make api calls from each of those projects to the a single service account that has the proper AIM roles. i have not been able to successfully set up a service account to access the ai processor we trained

SUMMARY: I have three different projects

1. ***DEV***
2. ***STAGING***
3. ***DOCUMENT AI PROCESSING***

The** *DOCUMENT AI PROCESSING*** project contains the *document AI processor* which was custom-trained and the 2 other environments listed above need to access the same endpoint. I cannot find the right way to configure this, at the moment i am getting the following error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'documentai.processors.processOnline' )

BACKGROUND:

(1) I created a service account

[image]

(2) I grant this service account access to project, but did not grant any users access to the service account (item 3 in the screenshot)

[image]

(3) service account created successfully

[image]

(4) i add (as a principal) the newly created service account to the ***DEV*** project and assign it *EXACTLY* the same roles as what it has in the ***DOCUMENT AI PROCESSING*** project

[image]

(5) the service account has been granted access to the ***DEV*** project

[image]

What I expect to happen is to be able to use the Document AI processor which is located in **DOCUMENT AI PROCCESSING** project from the **DEV** project**.** However, I am still receiving the same error: *PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'documentai.processors.processOnline' denied on resource '[//documentai.googleapis.com/project](https://documentai.googleapis.com/project)...'(or it may not exist)."*

After many hours, i am stumped and i am grateful to anyone that can provide an explanation of what i am getting wrong

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What I think I'd like to see in more detail is how you are INVOKING the DocAI processing from your DEV project.  I understand that the processor is defined in project "DOCAI-PROC" and being leveraged from "DEV" but I'm not yet understanding how you are specifying that.  It looks like it should be this API:  https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.processors.processorVersions/process

Comment: @Kolban thanks to the link you shared I figured out how to solve the issue and it was related to Authorization Scopes. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment exchange of @Kolban and @bismar eyner esquivel ortuste, the correct permissions needed must be added to the **Authorization Scope**.

You may refer to this [Document AI IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/access-control/iam-roles) documentation for the full list of roles for the API and refer to [Document AI Processor REST API](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.processors.processorVersions/process#authorization-scopes) documentation for more information.

Posting the answer as *community wiki* for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.